# Program to deploy SQL Server databases & updates

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I hope I am not creating any useless post here, but I actually could not find the solution I was looking for.

I am currently developing an application that uses 2 SQL Server databases. These databases will be deployed to customer servers but will change due to future updates, such as new stored procedures or fixes.

I am wondering what the best way is to do that?

In Visual studio it is pretty simple by using Schema compare, but I cannot require the customers to have visual studio installed, just because of schema compare functionality. Is there a simple way to compare databases with C#, by using .bak backups or online master databases?

Also what would your suggestion be in deploying databases to customer environments?

Best regards

Comment: Related: [How can I update my SQL Server database schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1171331)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the SSDT tools for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, you can create and deploy DACPACs with your application. As part of your installation, upgrade, you can utilize the SqlPackage.exe utility that will publish your changes and update the client on the fly.

Just add a Database Project to your solution, and do all your schema work out of there.

Check out this page as a good reference on where to start:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: DACPAC seem to be the solution I was looking for! Thanks!